# Magento 2 need to add extension attribute

Tags: magento2, extension-attributes

I am using magento 2.1.5 . I want to add extension attribute to `Magento\Tax\Api\Data\QuoteDetailsItemInterface` I want to add product id attribute to **QuoteDetailsItemInterface**

Can anyone suggest me how can I add attribute to **QuoteDetailsItemInterface**.

I have created custom module add below code to it.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Tax\Api\Data\QuoteDetailsItemInterface">
        <attribute code="product_id" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

Still I am trying to get product id

```
$item->getExtensionAttributes()->getProductId()
```

but It gives null value. Please suggest how can i get product id and how can i set product id to extension attribute.